# How to create a proper string using regex in java?

Tags: java

I try to create a value using regex in  java.

My email regex is  : `^[\\w]([\\w\\-\\.\\+\\'\\/]*)@([\\w\\-\\.]*)(\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,22}(\\.[a-zA-Z]{2}){0,2})$` .

My regex genetor create `7@.-_-.fzLc` this string.But i expected one proper emai.But it not created. So how to create proper meaningful value using regex in java

Comment: Isn't that a perfectly valid email address?

Comment: you will have to explain what "proper" means or nobody can help you

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do with the address that you're generating? There's almost definitely a better way.

Comment: regex is not the best suited to generate values which this regex would match.Check this tool: https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-from-regex. email addresses are not random strings. Also your regex is far too simple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression